# Android fragment nested in another fragment: getParentFragment() returns 0

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

Basically the situation is like this: I have an `Activity`, which displays a three `Fragments` within a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and within one of these `Fragment`, I nest another `Fragment`. I added the fragments like this:

```
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(rootView.getId(), new MainPageFragment(), "lpt2");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

When I try to call `getParentFragment()` inside of `MainPageFragment()`, it returns `null`.
How can that be? I checked multiple posts here on stackoverflow as well as on other blogs, and they all came to the conclusion that if you nest one fragment within another one, calling `getParentFragment` should return its parent fragment. Returning `null` means, that the parent is an activity as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29). Which is not the case. Please tell me I'm making some kind of silly mistakes :\

This is the `Fragment` that is a child to the main `Activity`

```
public class MainPage extends Fragment {

private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        global_var = new Global();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(rootView.getId(), new MainPageFragment(), "lpt2");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

This is the Fragment which is a child to the `Main Page Fragment`

```
public class MainPageFragment extends Fragment{
private View rootView;
private Fragment parentFragment;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_list, container, false);
    if (getParentFragment() == null) Log.i("damn", "it");
    return rootView;
   }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Please tell me if I need to provide more code, I extracted things like `ListView` and so on because I thought it would be irrelevant.

Edit: I'm using android.support.v4.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have pass `FragmentManager` reference to all of your Fragments from your `FragmentPagerAdapter` and then use `getParentFragment()`. May be this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I immidiately tried your approach, unfortunately it didn't work because I'm forced to use android.support.v4.app which doesn't allow for `findFragmentByTag(String)`. Also, I'm not sure if this approach works at all, since I have to call `getFragmentManager()` in my nested `Fragment`

Comment: see if you are using android.support.v4.app then you have to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). and by the way findFragmentByTag(String) is allow by both see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Comment: I tried that out, it gave me an error saying `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined for the type `MainPageFragment` as well as for `MainPage` :\

Comment: I think you have extend you activity with Activity, check this should be android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not simple Activity

Comment: I finally figured it out. Since I am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter´, I needed to pass a reference to the `FragmentManager` down to my Fragments, which then again returned a list, and with the id given I was able to get a reference to my parent fragment. But you gave me the right idea, so if you update your code, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: You need to make a reference to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` as I stated it in my post, otherwise your answer will be misleading for future readers

Comment: @GuntramGöres I don't know how you have used FragmentPagerAdapter. What I have describe here is how we can add and get fragments using backstack.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50022/discussion-between-guntram-gores-and-user3337034)

Comment: getParentFragment() was introduced in API level 17 (Android 4.2). Android 4.2 introduced the idea of nested fragments (fragments containing other fragments). Calling this results in null if the fragment has a parent which is an Activity.