# Android : Parent fragment of a nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

A `getParentFragment()` from my nested fragment is returning a `null`. I realise that getting a `null` means that the fragment is attached to the activity and not to the nested  container fragment. But I am explicitly nesting the child fragment inside the parent fragment using the child `FragmentManager` and thus think that I should not be getting a `null`. Could you tell me what I am missing?

**Parent fragment**

```
public class UsageBreakUp extends Fragment implements Filter.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

  ....

  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.filter, new Filter()).commit();
    }

...

}
```

**Child fragment**

```
public class Filter extends Fragment {

...


    public Filter() {
        if (getParentFragment() == null)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "parent fragment is null");
    }

...

}
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14804584/2591002)

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, I have already. It isn't helping. I've updated my question with this information.

Comment: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22501774/2591002)?? and are you sure you getting *getParentFragment()* NULL?? because it seems you are trying to cast Fragment to a listener which is throwing an exception

Comment: try this code :  `UsageBreakUp  = (UsageBreakUp) getParentFragment();` and tell me the output.. post LOGCAT too

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, It is `getParentFragement()` manager that is returning `null`. I have edited my question to make this point clear.

Comment: [Once go though this](https://gist.github.com/noxi515/4259065)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was calling `getParentFragment()` in the constructor of the child fragment and thus before the child fragment was fully created. Shifting `getParentFragment()` to `onCreateView()` solved the problem. Shifting wasn't an issue as I was calling `getParentFragment()` to check if the parent fragment had implemented a child fragment interaction listener.

Comment: I am getting the null even if I call from `onCreateView` as `this.parentFragment` in kotlin. Any solution for this?

Comment: My error happens because I had used `activity.supportFragmantManager` instead of `childFragmentManager`